# Test of takeUntil-using NGRX effect with jasmine-marbles does not complete as expected

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, nrwl, jasmine-marbles

Given two NGRX Effects (using nrwl/nx dataPersistence notation) where the second is bound to the first by `takeUntil`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ModuleEffects {

  @Effect() effectOne$ = this.dataPersistence.fetch(ModuleActionTypes.ActionOne, {
    run: (action: ActionOne, state: ModulePartialState) => {
     return new SomeReturnAction();
    },
  });

  @Effect() effectTwo$ = this.dataPersistence.fetch(ModuleActionTypes.ActionTwo, {
    run: (action: ActionTwo, state: ModulePartialState) => {
      return this.service.apiCall().pipe(
        takeUntil(this.effectOne$),
        map(result => new SomeResultAction(result))
      );
    },
  });
```

The intention is to stop emitting SomeResultAction due to UI input as soon as effectOne$ has emitted (which works fine).

I'm now attempting to test these effects using the jasmine-marbles lib:

```js
    it('should stop emitting after effectOne$ has emitted', () => {
      const action = new ActionTwo();
      const interruptingAction = new ActionOne();
      const outcome = new SomeResultAction(mockedResult);
      actions = hot('        -a--a-ia|', { a: action, i: interruptingAction });
      const expected = cold('-b--b--b|', { b: outcome });

      expect(effects.effectTwo$).toBeObservable(expected);
    });
```

This test succeeds even though I would expect the `expected` observable to complete after `interruptingAction` has been dispatched.

Comment: You ever find a resolution for this?

Comment: No, I actually haven't. But like an old ghost haunting me I've only recently picked up testing observables with rxjs-marbles again, I'm tempted to give this another look.